# How to intercept project save event in visual studio 2017 sdk?

Tags: visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

It's possible to intercept the project save event in visual studio 2017 sdk?

**UPDATE**

I'm currently developing an extension of visual studio 2017 where I need to know when any change is persisted.

Ex: When I add a new reference in the project (I know there are events for when the reference is added / changed / removed but did not meet my need), the project is marked as pending to be saved. I need to intercept it when it's saved (better if it is before saving).

I tried the `Dte.Events.DocumentEvents.DocumentSaved` event, but it is not triggered in the save project; `DTE.Events.SolutionEvents` and `DTE.Events.SolutionItemEvents` have no event of the type I need.

It is possible?

Comment: If I post the answer *Yes, it's possible*, will that suffice without my adding any details? If not, then your question is too vague and broad in scope, and you should [edit] to be more specific about what you're asking.

Comment: @KenWhite You're right! I edited my question...

Comment: Much better. Retracting my close vote. Thanks.

Comment: [Why is "Is it possible to..." a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7273/why-is-is-it-possible-to-a-poorly-worded-question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct one in this case would be to use implement `IVsRunningDocTableEvents3` overriding the `OnBeforeSave` method.

In this way, I know exactly when a project is to be saved and perform what it needs.

Ex.:

```
uint cookie;
var runningDocumentTable = (IVsRunningDocumentTable)GetGlobalService(typeof(SVsRunningDocumentTable));

runningDocumentTable.AdviseRunningDocTableEvents(new RunningDocTableEventsHandler(), out cookie);
```

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualStudio;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop;

namespace YourProject
{
    internal class RunningDocTableEventsHandler : IVsRunningDocTableEvents3
    {

        #region Methods

        public int OnAfterFirstDocumentLock(uint docCookie, uint dwRDTLockType, uint dwReadLocksRemaining, uint dwEditLocksRemaining)
        {
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int OnBeforeLastDocumentUnlock(uint docCookie, uint dwRDTLockType, uint dwReadLocksRemaining, uint dwEditLocksRemaining)
        {
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int OnAfterSave(uint docCookie)
        {
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int OnAfterAttributeChange(uint docCookie, uint grfAttribs)
        {
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int OnBeforeDocumentWindowShow(uint docCookie, int fFirstShow, IVsWindowFrame pFrame)
        {
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int OnAfterDocumentWindowHide(uint docCookie, IVsWindowFrame pFrame)
        {
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int OnAfterAttributeChangeEx(uint docCookie, uint grfAttribs, IVsHierarchy pHierOld, uint itemidOld, string pszMkDocumentOld, IVsHierarchy pHierNew, uint itemidNew, string pszMkDocumentNew)
        {
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        public int OnBeforeSave(uint docCookie)
        {
            /////// MY CODE ////////
            return VSConstants.S_OK;
        }

        #endregion Methods
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DTE.Events.DocumentEvents works with opened project files, not entire project system. Each project loaded and displayed in the solution explorer is loaded by the project system for that project's type. So different version of project has its own project system implementation.

According to your requirement, you need to implement IVsSolutionEvents3 to be notified of a project being loaded/unloaded. And register that object as a listener in your package initialization code via the SVsSolutionBuildManager service.

Then implement IVsHierarchyEvents to be notified of project changes and Call AdviseHierarchyEvents on the IVsHierarchy object passed to the IVsSolutionEvents3's OnAfterProjectOpen implementation to register the event listener object.

More detailed explanation, please refer to below thread.

[Visual Studio SDK - Handling File Add, Remove, and Rename Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35095241/visual-studio-sdk-handling-file-add-remove-and-rename-events)

Comment: I was able to implement as stated above, however, there is still no event to save the project. The methods that exist there are fired several times and do not fit well into what I need.

Is there another way?
If it does not exist, how can I identify that the project was saved by implementing `IVsHierarchyEvents`?

Comment: You could add a listener to monitor the OnItemAdded() method. For example, you could set a bool variable in OnItemAdded() method. When OnItemAdded called, the bool variable will be set to true, which means the project hierarchy has been changed.